# CSS: Row/Column action buttons alignment issue

Tags: html, css

I have HTML table where its rows and columns are dynamically created by angular js.
After a row/column has been added, I would like to have a option that when the user hovers over that row or column it would display a delete button icon clicking which would delete that row/column. For most of the part it works fine barring some issues as below.

Here is the code pen I have created. 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PBVoOb

Here is my table code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">        
      <thead>
        <tr class="actions">
          <th class="unique-id hidden-border" colspan="1"></th>
          <th ng-class="{'active': showColumnActions(c)}" ng-repeat="c in targetTable.columns track by $index"><span>
                     <a class="btn btn-xs"><i class="fa fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                     <a class="btn btn-xs" ng-click="removeColumn($index)"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>

          <th class="unique-id">ID #</th>
          <th contenteditable="true" ng-repeat="c in targetTable.columns" ng-model="c.label"></th>
          <th class="view-next-set"><a href="#">...</a></th>
          <td class="center add-column"><a href="#" ng-click="addColumn()">+ Add Column</a></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="r in targetTable.rows" ng-mouseover="row = $index" ng-mouseleave="row = -1">

          <td class="unique-id" ng-model="r.id">{{r.id}}<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
              <button ng-show="row == $index" type="button" class="btn" ng-click="deleteRow($index)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
            </div></td>
          <td contenteditable="true" ng-repeat="column in targetTable.columns" ng-model="r[column.id]" ng-blur="!r.id? addNewRow(r[column.id], r): undefined" ng-mouseover="setActiveColumn(column)"></td>
          <td class="blank" colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <!--<tr>
                 <td class="unique-id"></td>
                 <td contenteditable="true" ng-repeat="column in targetTable.columns" ng-model="entry" ng-blur="addRow(entry, column.id)"></td>
                 <td class="blank" colspan="2"></td>
              </tr> -->
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Issues:

- For Row: If you hover over the ID column it shows the delete (X) icon. I would like this icon to be displayed outside of the table on left side when they hover over to the ID column. How can I do that.
- For Column: 
  There is a top border extra above the table which keeps on extending when we keep clicking add column button. Not sure what causing this. How can I get rid of the extra border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use absolute positionning to avoid the cell to be resized and to let you set the button where you want.

for the extra empty row, remove :

```
  {}
```

from

```
var table = {
    id: 0,
    name: "table 14",
    columns: [{ id: 0, label: "Name" }, { id: 1, label: "Age" }],
    rows: [ 

// ... your datas 

],
    uniqueIdCounter: 1037
  };
```

where there is no data to print but it creates an extra empty row.

example

```
td {
  position: relative;/* be the reference for the absolute child */
}
div.btn-group {
  position: absolute ;/* do not disturb the flow */
  left: 0;/* let me be on the far left of my td parent */
}
```

below a a demo snippet.

```js
// Define the `ReportsMockUpsApp` module
angular.module("customControl", ["ngSanitize"]).directive("contenteditable", [
  "$sce",
  function($sce) {
    return {
      restrict: "A", // only activate on element attribute
      require: "?ngModel", // get a hold of NgModelController
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        var disable =
          attrs.contenteditable === "false" || !Boolean(attrs.contenteditable);
        if (!ngModel || disable) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

        // Write data to the model
        var read = function(value) {
          var html = element.html() || (typeof value === "string" ? value : "");

          // When we clear the content editable the browser leaves a <br> behind
          // If strip-br attribute is provided then we strip this out
          if (attrs.stripBr && html == "<br>") {
            html = "";
          }
          ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
        };

        // Specify how UI should be updated
        ngModel.$render = function() {
          element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(ngModel.$viewValue || ""));
        };

        // Listen for change events to enable binding
        element.on("blur keyup change", function() {
          scope.$evalAsync(read);
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
          read(ngModel.$modelValue); // initialize
        });
      }
    };
  }
]);

var app = angular.module("myApp", ["customControl"]);

// Define the `appController` controller on the `ReportsMockUpsApp` module
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  var table = {
    id: 0,
    name: "table 14",
    columns: [{
      id: 0,
      label: "Name"
    }, {
      id: 1,
      label: "Age"
    }],
    rows: [{
        "0": "Mark Smith",
        "1": 10,
        id: 1035
      },
      {
        "0": "Mathew Coley",
        "1": 54,
        id: 1036
      },
      // add a few to play with delete
      {
        "0": "Mark Smith",
        "1": 10,
        id: 1035
      },
      {
        "0": "Mathew Coley",
        "1": 54,
        id: 1036
      },
      {
        "0": "Mark Smith",
        "1": 10,
        id: 1035
      },
      {
        "0": "Mathew Coley",
        "1": 54,
        id: 1036
      },
    ],
    uniqueIdCounter: 1037
  };

  $scope.tables = [table];
  $scope.targetTable = $scope.tables[0];

  $scope.select = function(tbl) {
    $scope.selectedTable = tbl;
  };

  $scope.addColumn = function() {
    var columns = $scope.targetTable.columns,
      id = columns.length;
    $scope.targetTable.columns.push({
      id: columns.length,
      label: `Column ${id}`
    });
  };

  $scope.targetColumn = null;

  $scope.select = tbl => {
    $scope.selectedTable = tbl;
  };
  $scope.setActiveColumn = (column, active) => {
    $scope.targetColumn = active || active == null ? column : null;
  };
  $scope.showColumnActions = column => {
    return column && $scope.targetColumn == column && column.id != null;
  };
  $scope.deleteRow = function(index) {
    $scope.targetTable.rows.splice(index, 1);
  };
  $scope.updateColumn = (column, index) => {
    var label = column.label;

    if (column.id === undefined && label) {
      // new column
      var columns = $scope.targetTable.columns;
      column.id = columns.length;
      $scope.targetTable.columns.push({});
      return;
    } else if (column.id && label == "") {
      //remove existing column
      $scope.removeColumn(index);
    }
  };
  $scope.setColumnInactive = () => {
    $scope.targetColumn = null;
  };

  $scope.removeColumn = index => {
    //remove existing column
    $scope.targetTable.columns.splice(index, 1);
  };
  $scope.addNewRow = function(value, row) {
    if (!value || value === "" || typeof value !== "string") return;
    $scope.targetTable.rows.push({});
    debugger;
    row.id = $scope.targetTable.uniqueIdCounter++;
  };

  /*$scope.addRow = function(value, column) {    
    if(!value || value === "" || typeof value !== 'string') return;
    else if(column === "") return;
    
    // create new row
    var row = { id: 2000 };
    row[column] = value;
    $scope.targetTable.rows.push(row); 
    
    // clear last row cell..
    this.entry = "";   
    debugger;
  };*/

  /*$scope.viewColumns = function(start, end) {
    var columns = [];
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i ++) {
        columns.push(i);
    }
    return input;
  };*/

  $scope.read = function() {
    return JSON.stringify(table);
  };
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 60px 0px;
}

.data-table .nav-pills li {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.nav.nav-pills li span {
  padding: 20px;
}

.table .unique-id {
  width: 10px !important;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.table td,
.table th {
  width: 120px;
}

.table .center {
  text-align: center;
}

.table th.font-normal {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.table .view-next-set {
  width: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.table .add-column {
  width: 60px;
  font-size: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.table .unique-id,
.table td.blank {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.table tr.actions th {
  border: 0 !important;
  background-color: white !important;
  position: relative;
}

.table tr.actions th>span {
  display: none;
}

.table tr.actions th.active>span {
  display: block;
}

.table tr.actions th a {
  color: #4371bb;
}

.table tr.actions th a:hover {
  color: #28497d;
}

.table th span {
  display: block;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: -9px;
  right: -1px;
  background-color: #a6c8ff;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 7px;
  border-top-left-radius: 7px;
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
}

.table th.hidden-border {
  border: 0 !important;
  border-top: 3;
}

td {
  position: relative;
}

div.btn-group {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div class="panel panel-default data-table">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
          <li role="presentation" ng-class="{'active': targetTable == t}" ng-repeat="t in tables"><a href="#" ng-click="select(t)">{{t.name}}</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" ng-click="select(t)">+ Add Table</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr class="actions">
              <th class="unique-id hidden-border" colspan="1"></th>
              <th ng-class="{'active': showColumnActions(c)}" ng-repeat="c in targetTable.columns track by $index" ng-mouseover="setActiveColumn(c)" ng-mouseout="setColumnInactive()"><span>
                         <a class="btn btn-xs"><i class="fa fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                         <a class="btn btn-xs" ng-click="removeColumn($index)"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span>
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>

              <th class="unique-id">ID #</th>
              <th contenteditable="true" ng-repeat="c in targetTable.columns" ng-model="c.label"></th>
              <th class="view-next-set"><a href="#">...</a></th>
              <td class="center add-column"><a href="#" ng-click="addColumn()">+ Add Column</a></td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="r in targetTable.rows" ng-mouseover="row = $index" ng-mouseleave="row = -1">

              <td class="unique-id" ng-model="r.id">{{r.id}}
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
                  <button ng-show="row == $index" type="button" class="btn" ng-click="deleteRow($index)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td contenteditable="true" ng-repeat="column in targetTable.columns" ng-model="r[column.id]" ng-blur="!r.id? addNewRow(r[column.id], r): undefined"></td>
              <td class="blank" colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <!--<tr>
                     <td class="unique-id"></td>
                     <td contenteditable="true" ng-repeat="column in targetTable.columns" ng-model="entry" ng-blur="addRow(entry, column.id)"></td>
                     <td class="blank" colspan="2"></td>
                  </tr> -->
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="well well-sm"><code>{{read()}}</code></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Sorry but would it be possible to have this delete link outside the ID row instead. Like the way we have for columns. The issue is I am having ng-model on this row and somehow when i use this code the delete button doesnt shows up. So was wondering if we could have non visible column and when you hover over it then it shows the delete button. And secondly for the second question of my original post I am not talking about the extra row in my table. Right above the table there is an extra border/line, see when you hover above to column name there is a extra line.

Comment: @kaka1234 hello i'm not not so much good to understand genuine english , i might missunderstand your issue. a) the delete cross can have coordonates setting it outside of its `td`'s parent but  `td:hover`  state can be lost , where do you want it to stand from snippett's example ?  b) i am lost about this non visible column (do you need that delete button into an extra td/column) .  c) Notice that I only tested your codepen with Firefox. what is your browser reference ?

Comment: See this image I uploaded: https://ibb.co/caY0D9 I want the delete outside the first column. Is it possible? Similar to when you mouseover any column it shows the delete button on top of header.

Comment: @kaka1234 update the left coordonates. test `left: -1em;` instead `left: 0;`  ....